# Building and compiling C/C++ programs natively on Yocto

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gnu, yocto

I wish to compile some C/C++ programs on Yocto. I am not so familiar with OS. I know I can use cross compilers and integrate the programs into recipes.

I wish to compile the programs natively on the OS. I am able to see some basic libraries like `libstdc++`, `libm`, `libc`, `libgcc_s.so`.

I am clueless as on how to proceed further.

Comment: Last time I wrote an answer to a question you asked, you deleted the question instead of accepting the answer. I won't do that again.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can add `EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES += "tools-sdk"` in your `local.conf` or DISTRO configuration, but is a rather bad practise to go that way because in-target compilation does not scale well. On a yocto based project, one would rather use an SDK or write recipes.

You can find a lot of explanations as well as demonstratins on that particular topic here [Live Coding Session #3: SDKs](https://youtu.be/u1rzYRz83kc)